# Where to find com.apple.eawt.event* class reference

Tags: java, multi-touch, gestures, leap-motion

I have been working on integrating the LeapMotion (leapmotion.com) with OS X. I believe this is achievable via the use of the native LeapMotion API as well as the apple GestureUtilities package located in com.apple.eawt.event.*. I have searched all over the net and found a few examples, but I am a beginner and am having trouble finding a resource that makes sense or has all of the information about the EAWT package there.

Are there other alternatives for recognizing gestures and multitouch on OS X? (Third party API's or something)

I appreciate the help. I'm excited to be working with such a cool team of developers at Leap and want to get my application out there for all to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for AppleJavaExtensions library.
You can download it from the [following site](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/apple/AppleJavaExtensions/1.4/AppleJavaExtensions-1.4.jar!/com/apple/eawt/event/GestureAdapter.class?classDetails=ok), or you can simply add it to your pom.xml as dependency, if you are using Maven.